# How does the campaign scoring system work?

Tags: warcraft-2

At the end of each campaign mission, you get to see the statistics screen, which includes a cumulative score and a rank. How is the score calculated and how does it affect the rank?

Comment: The last rank in the above list is "Designer" at 280,000+ points

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [classic.battle.net](http://classic.battle.net/war2/basic/score.shtml), we get the following:

You get points for winning the scenario and for killing units.

- Winning Scenario: 500
- Critter: 1
- Peasant/Peon: 30
- Flying Machine/Zeppelin/Tanker: 40
- Footman/Grunt/Transport: 50
- Archer/Axe Thrower: 60
- Ranger/Berserker: 70
- Dwarves/Sappers/Knight/Ogre/Ballista/Catapult/Mage/Death Knight/Demon: 100
- Paladin/Ogre Mage: 110
- Legendary Hero/Submarine/Turtle: 120
- Destroyer/Gryphon/Dragon: 150
- Battleship/Juggernaut: 300
- Wall: 1
- Tower: 95
- Farm: 100
- Lumbermill/Runestone: 150
- Barracks/Oil Rig: 160
- Blacksmith/Shipyard: 170
- Foundry/Guard Tower/Refinery/Town Hall: 200
- Stables/Ogre Mound: 210
- Inventor/Alchemist: 230
- Church/Altar/Wizard's Tower/Temple: 240
- Cannon Tower: 250
- Aviary/Roost: 280
- Keep/Stronghold: 600
- Castle/Fortress: 1500

These point values are then added to get a rank per the following:

- Servant/Slave: 0 - 2000
- Peasant/Peon: 2001 - 5000
- Squire/Rogue: 5001 - 8000
- Footman/Grunt: 8001 - 18000
- Corporal/Slasher: 18001 - 28000
- Sergeant/Marauder: 28001 - 40000
- Lieutenant/Commander: 40001 - 55000
- Captain: 55001 - 70000
- Major: 70001 - 85000
- Knight: 85001 - 105000
- General: 105001 - 125000
- Admiral/Master: 125001 - 145000
- Marshall: 145001 - 165000
- Lord/Chieftan: 165001 - 185000
- Grand Admiral/Overlord: 185001 - 205000
- Highlord/War Chief: 205001 - 230000
- Thundergod/Demigod: 230001 - 255000
- God: 255001 - 280000
- ???: 280000+

Comment: That's impressive. I found something to this effect myself, but it talks about 'half of cost' of this or 'quarter of cost' of that and it doesn't list everything either. Confusing much. This answer's much better.

Comment: Oh, by the way... "???" is inaccurate.  Whoever designed the game came up with a different title than that.  I can only imagine that the person who created that list was leaving that as a surprise, so I won't spoil it here.  I will just say that there is an actual name for that rank.